# 15.10 Window Manager don't load properly

Tags: xorg, window-manager

Since yesterday my window managers don't load completely. There are no window controls or any panels visible.
Cinnamon for examplem goes straight to fallback mode; Unity doesn't throw an error but has no panels as well.
Programms, even with gui, work if I open them from the terminal.

Here is my .xsession-errors file content as I have the feeling it could have something to do with this: http://pastebin.com/wh4pmcPe

Do you have any idea what could help?

I already tried:

1. switch to nvidia-355 driver (instead of 358)
2. write a new xconfig-file (had this issue before)
3. reinstall the kernel 4.2.0-22
4. boot using kernel 4.2.0-21
5. fix broken packages with "apt-get -f install", nothing found
6. apt-get install --reinstall xorg

I have no idea what to try next. My try probably would be to reinstall Ubuntu after a backup.

New testing results: 
**this has to do with my user account!**

I created a new user and everything is working fine if I log in with this new account. 
What could cause this issue in my settings? 
What could I delete to force new configurations?

Thank you in advance! 
Have a nice New Year's Eve and a lucky 2016!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around for some hours I got tired of searching which config was the problem (as the other user worked fine) and just backed up my old home directory by renaming it, creating a new one instead - reboot and done.
A fresh start where I took from my old folder just the configurations I needed for some applications.